# Grunt task(s) to start/stop sinopia

Tags: gruntjs, npm

Is there a way I can start and stop sinopia as a grunt task? All tutorials I see use cli and I'd prefer a portable solution if possible.

I'm trying to develop a build system for a multimodule project where the modules are dependent on each other, my plan to attack this is to have each module publish itself to a local sinopia server during the build so that dependent modules will find it as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use grunt to run the `sinopia` command, but I don't think that's the question you're trying to ask.

Let me ask you: why do you want to start and stop `sinopia` more than once?  My understanding is that you start `sinopia` and leave it running, and it will let you publish packages to it and download them without having to restart it.

Which tutorial(s) are you following?  Perhaps that will help me understand your question.

Comment: I'm certainly not using it in a way it was meant. I'd like to start it at the start of my build, publish some artifacts to it throughout the build because other parts of the build will use these published artifacts, and bring it down when all is done

Comment: I should add that I'm looking for a rough equivalence to a multi module maven project. After spending some time on this I'm not so sure this particular question is relevant anymore though since at this point I think solution should probably work with bower